# How do I make a Facebook Page public?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-pages

I have a page that I administer and I want to make it public so I (or anyone) can go to

```
facebook.com/MyBusinessNameIsAwesome
```

And they will be able to see the page even if they're not logged in to Facebook (or if they're the googlebot).

How do I do that? I've found 3 tutorials and none of them are up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, if you have country restrictions on your permissions, it won't show up on the web, even in the countries you've allowed.  x out all the countries that are listed and then save changes.
Just worked for me!

Comment: It's not just countries. It's any kind of restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You need 25 likes and then you can request the vanity URL.

Comment: I have over 100 likes and a vanity URL. But if you're not signed in you don't see my page, you get the FB signin form.